# Programmatically manipulate content type select list

Tags: entities

I have a content type called Car which have several field two of them are select lists which I want to make some operations on them. When the user select a value form the first select list a bulk of values should be populated in the other select list, my question is WHERE to do this programmatically and some tips for HOW doing this? I hope my question is clear

best

Comment: try what you want and if you have problem we help you accompolish it, try and dont give up :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add AHAH/AJAX to your field. The hook should be placed in either a custom module or in your theme's settings.php file.

Drupal has many examples about this. [Here's for Drupal 6](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ahah_example!ahah_example.module/6) and [here's for Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/group/ajax_example/7).

[This specific example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_dependent_dropdown/7) from the links above seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks you dear hampusn, your answer seems to be very useful I will check this sol now, but I am wondering if there any ready module for this purpose?

Comment: The link I inserted at the bottom of my answer is an example which I believe gives you exactly what you want. It manipulates the second drop down based on what you choose in the first drop down. Please try to use that and we can help you if you get stuck.